# Monaco Editor restrictions for highlights selected words

Tags: monaco-editor

I have a huge text with a lot of the same words (1400 items). When I select the first word Monaco highlights just 999 the first same words. Please, suggest to me some options which adjustment this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, (I spent about 30 minutes reading many issues on this) this limit is not easily configurable, meaning you need to modify code.  Furthermore, it's probably better not to do this since the developers who decided on this limit did so with performance and usability in mind (avoid blocking, long pauses when operating on large files).

There are a bunch of issues which reference this in the vscode repo which uses monaco as its base text editor library:

- [Select all occurrences of current selection"can not select the contents of more than 1000 rows.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5887)
- [Select All Occurrences" is not selecting all of matches in large files (stops at 1000)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/7201)